# get.inducedSubgraph and loop function

Tags: r, for-loop, statnet

I have a list containing a network for each row (**sna.list.1**). 
For each of the networks, I need to extract a subgraph where only women are included, in order to calculate the density of women-only networks.
I have created a loop function to set vertex attributes

```
female=vector()
for (i in 1 : length (sna.list.1))
  set.vertex.attribute(sna.list.1[[i]],"Female",alter.list.1bis[[i][,"NIDemo1_c4"])
```

but when I tried to create the subgraph with get.inducedSubgraph I receive a warning message saying " Illegal vertex selection in get.inducedSubgraph". The same formula works if I applied it to just one row/network.

```
subnetwork2=vector()
for (i in 1 : length (sna.list.1))
subnetwork2[[i]]=get.inducedSubgraph(sna.list.1[[i]],v=which(sna.list.1[[i]]%v%"Female"=="1"))
```

does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: I think this is not `igaph`, at least `igraph` does not have a `get.inducedSubgraph` function.

Comment: it appears that you are using the `network` package, but without some additional code context I can't really tell what you are doing.  I'm not sure what you mean by "list containing a network for each row"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that [get.inducedSubgraph isolated alters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32360923/get-inducedsubgraph-isolated-alters)  is a continuation of your issue, it sounds like you were trying to induce a subgraph of size zero.  i.e. `v=which(sna.list.1[[i]]%v%"Female"=="1")` was returning `integer(0)` for some networks.

Ideally, since the `network` package supports networks of size zero (no vertices) `get.inducedSubgraph()` should return a network of size zero in this case, but it does not yet do that.